# Connect R to Sybase Database

Tags: r, sybase, rodbc

Can anyone share how to connect to a Sybase database in R?

I am doing this:

```
 con <- odbcConnect(dsn= "xxxxx", uid="xxxxx", pwd="xxxxx")#, rows_at_time = 500)
 data<-sqlQuery(con, "select * from test")
 data
 close(con)
```

and I get the error:

> first argument is not an open RODBC channel

---

Update: When I do this

```
library(RODBC)
con <- odbcDriverConnect("Driver={Adaptive Server     Enterprise};server=xxxxxx;database=xxxxxx;uid=xxxxx;pwd=xxxxx;port=xxxxxx")
    odbcGetInfo(con)
```

I get an error:

> Error in odbcGetInfo(con) : argument is not an open RODBC channel

Comment: What happens if you use  `odbcDriverConnect`  instead of `odbcConnect`.

Comment: @mnel I get he same error. any ideas?